# What are calculation methods to remove moire on raster grid?

Tags: raster, raster-calculator

Here's a raster that I calculate in PostGIS.

There are points of residential bulidings with population values *P*, and businesses with some value to them, say *X*. I calculate

> Sum(X) / Sum(P) for points within 500 m

And the map has artefacts that distract readers. They ask what that is and distrust the map.

[image]

(The red figures show areas that are uninhabbited and have no businesses there, but together the quotent increases, because the denominator drops.)

The problem is that whatever way I smooth it, a quotient has same problem with artefacts. Like if I smooth them by distance:

> Sum(X/(500-distance)*500) / Sum(P/(500-distance)*500) for points within 500 m

Of course, the distance factors in the numerator and in the denominator cancel each other.

Are there ways to fix this?

So far, I chose calculating averages by quarters:

[image]